# Exclude records from the first and last rows in a loop

Tags: vb.net

Below is my export to csv from listview using vb.net

```
Function ExportListview2CSV(ByVal lstview As ListView) As Boolean
        Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
        Dim csvFileContents As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim CurrLine As String = String.Empty
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV|*.csv"
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an CSV File"

        csvFileContents.AppendLine("Service Provider Name: |" & cbodestproname.Text)
        'csvFileContents.AppendLine(cbodestproname.Text)

        csvFileContents.AppendLine("Circel Name: |" & cbodestcirclename.Text)
        'csvFileContents.AppendLine(cbodestcirclename.Text)

        csvFileContents.AppendLine("Month: |" & dtpDate.Text)
        '  csvFileContents.AppendLine(dtpDate.Text)

        csvFileContents.AppendLine("Type of File: |" & cbotypeoffile.Text)
        '  csvFileContents.AppendLine(cbotypeoffile.Text)


        csvFileContents.AppendLine("")
        'Write out the column names as headers for the csv file.
        For columnIndex As Int32 = 1 To lstview.Columns.Count - 2
            CurrLine &= (String.Format("{0}|", lstview.Columns(columnIndex).Text))
        Next
        'Remove trailing comma
        csvFileContents.AppendLine(CurrLine.Substring(0, CurrLine.Length - 1))
        CurrLine = String.Empty
        'Write out the data.
        For Each item As ListViewItem In lstview.Items
            For Each subItem As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In item.SubItems
                CurrLine &= (String.Format("{0}|", subItem.Text))
            Next
            'Remove trailing comma
            csvFileContents.AppendLine(CurrLine.Substring(0, CurrLine.Length - 1))
            CurrLine = String.Empty
        Next
        'Create the file.
        If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            If saveFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then
                Dim Sys As New System.IO.StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName)
                Sys.WriteLine(csvFileContents.ToString)
                Sys.Flush()
                Sys.Dispose()
                MsgBox("Data's are Saved Succesfully to " & saveFileDialog1.FileName, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            End If
        End If


    End Function
```

i want to exclude the records from the 1st and last rows 
where should i make chages in above code

plz help me

thanx in advance.

Comment: you should trim the example code to the minimum. also, this question has little to nothing to do with the export to the CSV format, so the title is misleading

Answer (score 1):

You might use

```
For i as Integer = 1 to lstview.Items.Count - 2

...

Next
```

that will start from the second item and stop before the last item

Answer (score 0):

yeah, you should use an index other than for each to iterate the items in listview